# Will I be able to play my Steam games when I move from Russia to Germany? If not, what can I do?

Tags: steam, region-lock

I will move to Germany this Tuesday and live there for one year. But I have bought all of my Steam games in Russia (where I currently live), and some of the copies are likely region-restricted. Will I be able to play them? If not, is it possible to "upgrade" the game to the full, not region-restricted version?

I tried to search for [steam](/questions/tagged/steam) and words like "abroad", "region", but didn't find anything.

I would prefer answers from other Russians who have been to Germany, but if you back your answer up with official answers from Valve, that is also OK.

Comment: There is a Steam support page on region restrictions, which seems like it only matters where the game was bought unless the game page states differently. However, it doesn't cover moving to a different country, only travelling. You can read through it here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1266-QFZC-2141

Comment: According to Reddit you can get locked out of some games, but if you can provide your ID and stuff you can ask the Steam support to unlock them.

Comment: @dly Could you pls link to that Reddit post?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I posted it in the answer now

Comment: To be save you could contact the steam-support now and warn them. If you have trouble with steam while being in germany just contact them again. If you warn them now it doesn't look like a petty excuse.

Comment: FWIW I have moved from Poland to UK to US back to UK to Germany and then back to US and I haven't got any games which were locked out (that I noticed). I didn't need to send them any documents (just card).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I've gotten around a lot as well and never got locked out. But just because it didn't happen to us it doesn't mean this does never happen.

Comment: @dly True (and that why it was comment not answer) but the more people it didn't happened to the less likely it will happen to OP. I imagine the Valve is trying to limit resale of accounts so any lockouts are due to false positives and, in grand scheme of things unlikely.

Comment: you can also set up a VPN for gaming use.

Comment: @SargeBorsch VPN is a direct road to suspension.

Comment: if that is the case then it's not good to deal with them at all, because blocking VPNs is too invasive

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka AIUI steam only region locks for markets in which games are sold at a significant discount. From some googling it seems that poles get charged the regular European prices, so there is no need to impose region locks on them.

Comment: I plan to choose an answer to accept when I actually move and see the result. I have contacted the support and notified of my plans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have to accept an answer that "worked for me", so I have to write my own: not a single problem I have seen, even though I had a RU/CIS version of, for example, Bioshock Infinite. I can still install it (the button is active, the download starts) and likely also play it (I don't want to download 40 GB to test it now).

Probably because Steam didn't receive a single German payment from me yet, probably because the game was bought pretty long ago (summer 2016). But I will watch what happens later and check if it still works.

What is also interesting: when I open Steam Store, at first it shows me the price in Euro, but after ~1 second the page refreshes and I start to see it in Russian rouble.

Answer (score 36):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3j85xv/leaving_russia/) you *can* get locked out, but you can contact Steam support to get your games back:

> Hello fellow Russian.
>
> I've moved to the EU several years years ago and had some games which
>   were locked-out. Here's what I've done: I wrote to the steam support
>   and asked what can I do about it. I got asked the following scans: ID,
>   Address Card and a paid bill for this address. After this my locked
>   games became available to me.

Comment: Of course, some titles might actually be unsanctioned for sale in some places due to trade or licensing restrictions.  I don't use Steam, so I don't know how they handle such situations.

Answer (score 11):

I've moved from Russia to US and I have no problems playing my games or buying new ones.

Comment: Did you check all of your games before and after moving? Also, I can guarantee you that there are differences between the Russian and US Steam stores.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga There are more than 1000, so I did not check them all. I have never noticed a single change. And I think that my store is still Russian.

Comment: The store contents are different depending on what region you are in. You can change the language settings, but you can't normally buy games that are not available in your region. Then again, the US might have more games available than Russia, meaning you didn't miss out on any content because you moved in the right direction (as far as game availability goes).

Comment: I did not change the region manually and it has not changed automatically yet (more than a year). There are very few games not available in Russia (I cannot name any myself), so I'm not pressed to change it.

Comment: Are you using a Russian credit card as your payment method? I recall being able to buy from the Swedish store (after a few emails back and forth with support) even after going overseas, if I were using a Swedish card.

Comment: I was using my old card at first, but then I've switched it to US-issued one. Maybe, I'm just lucky... Or maybe I forgot to change the address. This happens.

Comment: The question specifically asked for Germany, where there are censorship and political correctness laws which might ban some games.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: definitely don't worry about it. Even if some tiny minority of games get blocked you can always use VPN to pretend you're still in Russia.

Some games are region-specific and might get you geo-locked out of them. But most games are totally fine to play globally. I bought all my games in the China store, which has the same much lowered price as those in the Russian store, but I'm playing it in HK and in Germany. The only game that got geo-blocked was *Deus Ex: Human Revolution, Director's Cut* (which I think was specifically listed as region-exclusive). Steam wouldn't let me install the game, and even if I installed it, I couldn't launch it without a VPN pretending that I'm in Asia-Pacific.

Comment: That's gonna get you banned

Comment: @aytimothy Any reference for that? Especially when you're playing a single player game? Why do they even ban you if you're playing on your own.