# I'm moving to the U.S. in a few months; what will happen to the games in my Indian Steam library?

Tags: steam, region-lock

Everything that's in my Steam library has been purchased from the Indian Steam Store. What will happen to them when I move? Will I still be able to play them or will they be locked?

Comment: Some games on Steam have special handling of regional pricing and sales restrictions, and you may not be able to get them in a different language when you move, or you won't be able to play on your new locale's servers. You'd either have to buy a new copy intended for the new region or figure that out with help from Steam support.

Answer (score 25):

While I cannot find any official Steam documentation (there are lot's of reddit posts however, [this one for example](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2zu0ld/moving_to_another_country_do_i_need_to_do/)), I can share my own experience.

I moved from Russia to the U.S. in 2017, and this is what happened:

1. Currency in my wallet was converted to USD.
2. My shop is now US shop - all prices are in USD.
3. All my games are in place, I can download and play them.
4. All my inventory is untouched. After grace period I was able to sell / buy items on community market again.
5. Some of my games were originally region-locked to Russia - and they still are! For example, I have Rainbow Six: Siege - for me it had only russian localization. When I reinstalled it in the US - it still was in Russian! No problems with playing on NA servers though.

I think for India situation should be the same. However, there is additional censorship for games in some other countries - see concerns about it in [Will I be able to play my Steam games when I move from Russia to Germany? If not, what can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311263/144891) .

Comment: In my case few (out of several hundreds) games stopped working: Skyrim and Borderlands 2. Borderlands 2 was a very fresh purchase at that moment, so Steam support agreed to refund it. Skyrim I had to purchase again. And country conversion for the account had to be done through support as well, sending scans of my local ID to prove new residency. That was in 2012.

Comment: You can check which games are region-locked using SteamDB, on an individual basis, though I don't remember how.

Comment: I moved from the US to Sweden in 2009 and my experience was similar, except I didn't have any region-locked games in the first place (so #5 did not apply). Everything Just Worked(tm) after I moved.